# Javascript debugger plugin for Netbeans 6.9

Tags: netbeans

How do I install Javascript debugger plugin for netbeans 6.9. I installed it today but cannot find support for javascript debugging.

In the tools/plugins dialog, it is not listed anywhere.

I am new to netbeans and I have fedora 13 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

Use firebug plug-in !!! with Mozilla firefox...
After installing press F12 and go to console tab for finding javascript errors, if any...
Also configure netbeans to use firefox as the default browser..  :)